# How to get the value of an attribute using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, attributes, nokogiri

I am trying to get the value `12:40 PM - 1 Mar 2016` from `data-original-title` within the following block of code using Nokogiri:

```
<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-joinDateText js-tooltip u-dir" dir="ltr" data-original-title="12:40 PM - 1 Mar 2016">Joined March 2016</span>
```

I successfully reach the global node:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff7899f7b60 name="span" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff7899f9ec4 name="class" value="ProfileHeaderCard-joinDateText js-tooltip u-dir">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff7899f9e9c name="dir" value="ltr">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff7899f9e88 name="title" value="3:40 AM - 1 Mar 2016">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff7899f8790 "Joined March 2016">]>]
```

using this code `Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://twitter.com/F_Casadei?lang=en")).css(".ProfileHead‌​erCard-joinDateText.js-tooltip.u-dir")`

But I can't reach this specific value.

Comment: The value `3:40 AM - 1 Mar 2016` doesn't exist in the HTML tag. Perhaps you meant `12:40 PM - 1 Mar 2016` which does exist? We'd like to see your code. While it looks like you tried something, showing your code helps us fix it, not just toss out unrelated answers. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve]".

Comment: @the Tin Man Sorry, here is my code `Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://twitter.com/F_Casadei?lang=en")).css(".ProfileHeaderCard-joinDateText.js-tooltip.u-dir")` and you are right, I am trying to get `"12:40 PM - 1 Mar 2016"`

Comment: Please add the code to the question by editing it, adding the change where you would have if you'd inserted it initially. Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags in the text; We can see what's changed and when if we need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's idiomatic to access parameter values by treating the node as a hash:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="foo"></div>')
doc.at('div')['class'] # => "foo"
```

And, just like a hash, you can assign to it too:

```
doc.at('div')['class'] = 'bar'
puts doc.to_html 

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><div class="bar"></div></body></html>
```

See [`[]`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#%5B%5D-instance_method) and [`[]=`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#%5B%5D%3D-instance_method) "[Modifying Nodes and Attributes](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html#modifying_nodes_and_attributes)" in the documentation.

Comment: When trying to grab a 'href' attribute value, it errored for me with "TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)", but the @Eugen's solution worked. I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [attr](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#attr-instance_method) method:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-joinDateText js-tooltip u-dir" dir="ltr" data-original-title="12:40 PM - 1 Mar 2016">Joined March 2016</span>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
span = doc.at('span').first
title = span.attr('data-original-title')
```

Comment: Rather than `css('span').first`, use `at('span')`. It does the same thing but is easier to read and saves typing.